# Using pure JavaScript code from an Angular 2 or 4 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Would it be possible to use https://conversejs.org/ in an Angular 2 or 4 application?

Is it possible to import and use JavaScript libraries from a TypeScript app?

This article claims it is possible:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/javascript-libraries-in-a-typescript-application-revisited/

Yet my front-end developer says it’s impossible.

Can someone verify?

Comment: This provides some general step by step instructions.https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af  Best bet to see if it is possible is to try those directions and see if it works with the library you need.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, and the TypeScript transpiler will convert your code into JavaScript during compilation. Therefore, you can write as much pure JavaScript in a TypeScript app and it should transpile to JavaScript with no issues.

> Is it possible to import and use JavaScript libraries from a TypeScript app?

Yes, it is possible. You will still need to appropriately declare/import the JavaScript libraries you want to use or else you will get compile errors.

> Would it be possible to use https://conversejs.org/ in an Angular 2 or 4 application?

This really depends on the library. The general answer is "Yes, you can use JavaScript libraries/code in a TypeScript app." But you will personally need to read the documentation in order to verify for this particular library.